# Swift google mobile ads send endless request to server

Tags: ios, swift, admob, google-mobile-ads

On our iOS app we are using "google mobile ads sdk" and its send too much request to their server with this url:

```
 "https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?..."
```

Is this a problem with sdk or is it a problem in my implementation how can I check this problem. Did you face any problem like this?

Here is the request list. It never stop sending request everysecond.
[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem, could you find the answer?

Comment: No we still have the same problem. I'm not sure but I think its because of webView. Is there any webView on your app ? @BurcuK.Kutluay

Comment: I don't use web view at that page. Its just listing page, but keeps requesting. I tried using Manuel impression for banner views and recording them, I will check if it keeps requesting. I will confirm with the answer If I find out what's is wrong really. Thank you.

Comment: I sent the report to google ads team. They will reply it as soon as possible, I will let you know if I find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @BurcuK.Kutluay thank you so much I will be waiting you.

Comment: @BurcuK.Kutluay hey, did you find the solution?

Comment: they just mailed back and offered to ask forums. So they said they do not have information about that. But I added record impression so I saw these requests does not create a problem. match request and impressions are equal.